# How do you properly configure gatsby-source-prismic-graphql preview functionality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

I'm using the [gatsby-source-prismic-graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql#differences-from-gatsby-source-prismic) plugin, and I'm trying to properlly configure it's Prismic preview functionality.

**Expected functionality** 
From Prismic CMS' editor on an already published document, I make a change, save, and I click the eyeball preview button. I want to be redirected to my local Gatsby + Prismic instance, redirected to the desired page, and see the change I made.

**What's actually happening** 
I make the change on Prismic CMS, click preview, and am redirected to `localhost:8000/` and not the desired page I'd like to preview.

Following [Prismic's troubleshooting article](https://user-guides.prismic.io/en/articles/3403530-troubleshooting-previews) section on "Can you see the preview cookie in the browser?" I am able to see the preview changes I made, indicating that "the problem is in the code."

**Is my `linkResolver.js` or `gatsby-config.js` not properly configured?**

`src/utils/linkResolver.js`

```
exports.linkResolver = function linkResolver(doc) {

  // Route for customers page
  if (doc.type === 'Customers') {
    return "/" + doc.uid;
  }

  // Homepage route fallback
  return '/'
}
```

**Relevant section of**  `gatsby-config.js`

```
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-prismic-graphql',
      options: {
        repositoryName: 'my-repo', // (REQUIRED, replace with your own)
        accessToken: `${process.env.API_KEY}`, // (optional API access token)
        path: '/preview', // (optional preview path. Default: /preview)
        previews: true, // (optional, activated Previews. Default: false)
        pages: [
          { // (optional, builds pages dynamically)
            type: 'Customers',         // TypeName from prismic
            match: '/customers',  // Pages will be generated under this pattern
            path: '/customers-preview', // Placeholder route for previews
            component: require.resolve('./src/templates/customers.js'),
          },
        ],
      }
    }
```

**Prismic Preview Settings** 
Here's a picture of my [Prismic preview settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESBrS.png).

Domain: `localhost:8000`

Link Resolver: `/preview`

Answer (score 0):

Can you post here the code where you are passing the linkResolver, it is possible that 'doc.type' is returning an undefined, because in graphQL you need to pass the _meta which includes the UID of your page.

You can also check this [document](https://prismic.io/docs/gatsby/rendering/rendering-content-relationships#2_0-linking-to-a-document-from-a-content-relationship) of how to configure linkResolver.

so **if** your code is like this:

```
   <a href={Link.url(document.generic_link, linkResolver)}>Go to page</a>
```

And your GraphQL query is like this

```
    generic_link {
      ... on PRISMIC_Linked_page {
        _linkType
        _meta {
          uid
        }
      }
    }
```

**Then** your linkResolver should be like this:

```
linkResolver(doc) {
  if (doc.type === 'page') {
    return `/${doc._meta.uid}`
  }
  return '/'
}
```